# Irobot Create encoders

Tags: ros, irobot-create, irobot-create-2-1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am programming my iRobot Create robot with ROS, but I have not found the encoders.

Is it posible to use the encoders for the iRobot Create robot using ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62035/irobot-create-encoders/) by [andreapatri](https://answers.ros.org/users/1713/andreapatri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I should be possible. You don't see an /odom topic using rostopic list?

http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/Writing_A_Simple_Node_that_Moves_the_iRobot_Create_Robot

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2